# setear checkbox a true en angular

Tags: angular, checkbox

tengo varios `checkbox` pero no puedo hacer que en mi modelo el valor  `booleano` falso cambie a `true`.

**en mi componente.ts tengo inicializado el modelo de esta manera**

```
this.listaMembresia = new ItemMembresia(0, "", 0, 0, 0, 0, false);
```

en el html lo he hecho de varias maneras y el valor no cambia

```
<input type="checkbox" name="limite_semana" [checked]="listaMembresia.limite_semana" >
<input type="checkbox" name="2" [(ngModel)]="listaMembresia.limite_semana">
<input type="checkbox" name="limite_semana" [value]="true" [checked]="listaMembresia.limite_semana" >
```

lo he intentado de esas maneras y no consigo resultado, espero alguien me pueda ayudar

```
export class ItemMembresia 
{
    constructor(
        public id:Number,
        public nombre:String,
        public costo:Number,
        public duracion:Number,
        public tiempo:Number,
        public limite_por_dia:Number,
        public limite_semana:Boolean
    ){}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema se parece mucho a uno que resolví hace poco. Trataba de asignar desde código valores a checkboxes y listas de selección y mis scripts fallaban (pareciendo correctos a la luz de la documentación que conocía).
Mi caso se diferencia del tuyo en que yo trataba de asignar valores usando JQuery vía `$(selector).attr(nombre_atributo, valor)` leyendo la documentación de JQuery encontré un comentario al respecto (no recuerdo el enlace) en el que se indicaba que debía hacerse vía `$(selector).prop(nombre_propiedad, valor)` donde nombre_propiedad = nombre_atributo. Lo utilicé y problema resuelto, mis asignaciones vía código cambian efectivamente el atributo value de los elementos cuando lo necesito.

Ofrecían como justificación al uso de `prop` en lugar de `attr` un comentario parecido al siguiente: los atributos de los elementos html se preservan, no así sus propiedades que si cambian. Si los atributos pudiesen ser modificados, sería imposible resetear una página a su estado original. De modo que se debe actuar sobre propiedades mas que sobre atributos, aunque hay una pseudocoincidencia de fondo entre atributos y propiedades; algo así como: el atributo es el valor de la propiedad al momento de construir el objeto, mientras que la propiedad es su valor presente.

Y, por abuso de lenguaje nos referimos a esa dualidad del valor usando genéricamente el término atributo, sin darnos cuenta de que este no es su valor presente. Una sutileza aburridora que hace que perdamos horas y horas buscando errores que no existen.

Espero que esta sugerencia sea de utilidad.

Comment: la verdad esta raro por que el otro amigo me dice que con él si quizo y ademas me fijo en consola que realmente el checkbox esta como true pero el valor no me lo recibe el modelo

Comment: Te resumo un poco mi caso, la consola me mostraba unas asignaciones, las que esperaba, al postear los formularios, el servidor recibía los valores originales. Por eso tuve que revisar el modo como asignaba valores. Y eso motivó que comentara. Pensé tratar de ahorrarte tiempo al sugerirte que trates de asignar propiedades si vas a cambiar valores durante la ejecución.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías compartir más información sobre el constructor y los atributos de la clase ItemMembresia. Acabo de hacer una prueba con [(ngModel)] y no tengo problema alguno.

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="test.limite_semana">
```

Y en el ts:

```
public test: any = { limite_semana: false };
```

Comment: este es el constructor completo

export class ItemMembresia 
{
    constructor(
        public id:Number,
        public nombre:String,
        public costo:Number,
        public duracion:Number,
        public tiempo:Number,
        public limite_por_dia:Number,
        public limite_semana:Boolean
    ){}
}

Answer (score 0):

Intenta esto:

```
export class ItemMembresia 
{
    public id:Number;
    public nombre: String;
    public costo: Number;
    public duracion: Number;
    public tiempo: Number;
    public limite_por_dia: Number;
    public limite_semana: Boolean;

    constructor(){}
}
```

Comment: Puedes verificar el estado de listaMembresia, agregandolo en el html de esta forma:

<h1>{{ listaMembresia.limite_semana }}</h1>